# Can I pool data sets answering identical question for different examples for moderation multiple regression analysis?

Tags: multiple-regression, interaction, pooling

I am currently doing research on the moderation effect of the aim on factors (independent variables) that influence technology acceptance (dependent variables). My research is as follows:

- Group A had to answer questions about Aim A
- Group B had to answer questions about Aim B

Additional information:

- The **questions** the groups answered used a Likert-scale and were **identical**.

Each questionnaire item naturally return a different variable name for each group. For example, acceptance (A) is returned in group A as A.A and in group B as A.B.

**Can I now pool these variables in one overarching variable to test for the moderation effect of the Aim on the relation between the independent variables that were measured and the dependent variable ?**

Thanks in advance for helping me!

Answer (score 0):

**Yes you can**. You might need an additional variable to represent the "Aim". I guess "Aim" is some kind of conditions, which is identically expressed in "group". If it is the case, Group B only had to answer to questions about Aim B. Then the group variable will suffice. If not, you will need the additional variable.